# Get the id of an element of a GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I made a query to group all the Audits belonging to a specific Area, like in the next query.

```
SELECT id_Area as idArea, area.Name as area_name, GROUP_CONCAT(id_Audit) as Audits 
FROM helios.fsa_audits 
LEFT JOIN helios.fsa_areas area USING (id_Area)
WHERE id_Auditor='4' 
GROUP BY id_Area;
```

As result I get this:

[image: QUERY Result]

I made this to get a datatable in the view like this:

[image: datatable in a view]

But What I need is to get the id of the Audit at the moment of click each button in the Auditorias.
I'm working with symfony, and I render the datatable like this:

```
<table aria-describedby="dataTable_info" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover dataTable" id="dataTable" role="grid" style="width:100%;" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Areas</th>
            <th>Auditorias</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for audit in auditsByArea %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ audit.area_name }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% for i in 1..4 %}
                        <input  class ="auditBtn mx-2" value="{{'W' ~ i }}" href="" data-id="{{ audit.Audits }}" data-area="{{ audit.area_name }}"id="auditBtn" name="auditBtn" type='text' readonly  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#auditModal"></input>
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
            </tr> 
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it does not put the one id per button(Audit), it assigns all the id's in all the buttons:

```
data-id="10,11,12,13"
```

Any idea or suggestion about how to get it?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the result set and the desired display !?!?

Comment: in the datable each area has the audits(the green squares), in the result set one area has 4 audits. those audits are displayed in the datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in symfony but you should explode your `group_concat` result

```
  my_array = explode({{ audit.Audits }});
```

then in you loop refer to the content on the array

```
  <td>
      {% for i in 1..4 %}
          <input  class ="auditBtn mx-2" value="{{'W' ~ i }}" href="" data-id="{{ my_array[i] }}" data-area="{{ audit.area_name }}"id="auditBtn" name="auditBtn" type='text' readonly  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#auditModal"></input>
      {% endfor %}
  </td>
```

Comment: Thanks actually it works it just assign one id per audit(green square), but now that id is assigned in the whole row, in the in the audits(green squares) on the sides

Comment: Sorry I didn't change the i in the array[], thank you so much you saved me